# C++ System data transfer design

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm designing a data transferring that supports an IoT framework I'm developing, which targets embedded systems.

A unified communication core is built, wherein each entity of the code can hook its requests sources (name and callback function) into a core (called SystemInterface), which is an entity that's responsible for interfacing requests. Thus interface requests for any new communication medium goes already supported.

The current design is limited in transferring `std::string` payloads, however, I want to upgrade this part to support transferring raw data also, and being generic.

The current callback function signature is:

```cpp
std::function<std::pair<ERROR_CODE,std::string>(const std::string& resourceLink, const std::string& payload)>;
```

Which I'm designing to upgrade to:

```cpp
std::function<std::pair<ERROR_CODE,std::vector<Data>>(const std::string& resourceLink, const std::vector<Data>& payload)>;
```

For the `Data` class, the proposed design goes to utilize `std::span<uint8_t>` as a "pointer" to the data payload.

And for the `std::vector<Data>` part, I'm thinking of making it generic, with any number of Data inputs that might be useful for some parts of the system.

I'm seeking feedback for the `Data` design, as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

#define INITIALIZE_COPY 0

using namespace std;
void print(string context)
{
    cout << context << endl;
}
void print(span<uint8_t const> data)
{
    cout << "span s:" << data.size() << "=[";
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << (int)*it;
        if (it != data.end() - 1)
            cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << "]." << endl;
}

enum Type
{
    BINARY, // Raw
    STRING
};
class Data
{
            Type                _type;
            vector<uint8_t>     _copy;
            span<uint8_t>       _span;

            void                reset()
                                {
                                    _copy.clear();
                                    _span = span<uint8_t>();
                                }

public:
            size_t              size()          { return _span.size(); }
            uint8_t*            data()          { return &_span[0]; }
            span<uint8_t>       as_span()       { return _span; }
            string_view         as_string_view() { return string_view(reinterpret_cast<char *>(_span.data()), _span.size()); }
            string              as_string()     { return string{_span.begin(), _span.end()}; }
    
            vector<uint8_t>     as_vector()
                                        {
                                            cout << "as_vector() _copy.size()=" << _copy.size() << endl;
                                            return _copy.size() ? _copy : vector<uint8_t>{_span.begin(), _span.end()};
                                        }

            void                set_type(Type type) { _type = type; }

    /* Constructors */
    Data(const std::string &str) : _type(STRING), _span(str.length() ? (span<uint8_t>(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str.data())), str.length() + 1)) : span<uint8_t>{})
    {
        print("std::string constructor");
    }

    Data(const std::string &&str) : _type(STRING), _copy(vector<uint8_t>{str.begin(), str.end()}), _span(_copy.data(), _copy.size())
    {
        print("std::string constructor");
    }

    Data(string_view sv) : _type(STRING), _span(span<uint8_t>{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(&sv.front())), sv.size()})
    {
        print("std::string_view constructor");
    }

    Data(const char *str, size_t length = 0, bool copy = false) : _type(STRING)
#if INITIALIZE_COPY
                                                                  ,
                                                                  _copy(copy ? vector<uint8_t>{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str)), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str)) + (length ? length : strlen(str))} 
                                                                                : vector<uint8_t>()),
                                                                  _span(copy ? &_copy.front() 
                                                                            : reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str))
                                                                            , length ? length : strlen(str))
#endif
    {
        print("const char* constructor");
#if !INITIALIZE_COPY
        if (copy)
        {
            // _copy=vector<uint8_t>{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(const_cast<char*>(str)), (uint8_t*) str+(length?length:strlen(str))};
            std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str)), length, back_inserter(_copy));
            _span = span<uint8_t>(&_copy.front(), length);
        }
        else
        {
            // Rely on the implicit constructor of _copy.
            _span = span<uint8_t>(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<char *>(str)), length ? length : strlen(str));
        }
#endif
    }

    Data(const uint8_t *data, size_t length, bool copy = false) : _type(BINARY), _copy(copy ? vector<uint8_t>{data, data + length} : vector<uint8_t>()), _span((copy ? &_copy.front() : const_cast<uint8_t *>(data)), length)
    {
        print("const uint8_t* constructor");
    }

    Data(vector<uint8_t> &data) : _type(BINARY), _span(data.data(), data.size())
    {
        print("const vector<uint8_t>& constructor");
    }

    Data(vector<uint8_t> &&data) : _type(BINARY), _copy(data), _span(_copy.data(), _copy.size())
    {
        print("const vector<uint8_t>&& constructor");
    }

    Data(const Data &rhs) : _type(rhs._type)
    {
        print("Copy constructor");
        cout << "\trhs._copy.size()=" << rhs._copy.size() << endl;
        if (rhs._copy.size())
        {
            _copy = rhs._copy;
        }
        else
        {
            std::copy(rhs._span.begin(), rhs._span.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
        }
        _span = span<uint8_t>{_copy.begin(), _copy.end()};
    }

    Data &operator=(const Data &rhs)
    {
        print("Copy assignment operator");
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            _type = rhs._type;
            _copy.clear(); // Ensure no current copied memory.
            if (rhs._copy.size())
            {
                _copy = rhs._copy;
            }
            else
            {
                std::copy(rhs._span.begin(), rhs._span.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
            }
            _span = span<uint8_t>{_copy.begin(), _copy.end()};
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Data(Data &&source) : _type(source._type)
#if INITIALIZE_COPY
                          ,
                          _copy(source._copy.size() ? std::move(_copy) 
                                : vector<uint8_t>{source._span.begin(), source._span.end()})
#endif
    {
        print("Move constructor");
#if !INITIALIZE_COPY
        if (source._copy.size())
        {
            std::move(source._copy.begin(), source._copy.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
        }
        else
        {
            std::copy(source._span.begin(), source._span.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
        }
#endif
        _span = span<uint8_t>{_copy.begin(), _copy.end()};

        source.reset();
    }

    Data &operator=(Data &&source)
    {
        print("Move assignment operator");
        _type = source._type;
        if (this != &source)
        {
            if (source._copy.size())
            {
                std::move(source._copy.begin(), source._copy.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
            }
            else
            {
                std::copy(source._span.begin(), source._span.end(), back_inserter(_copy));
            }
            _span = span<uint8_t>{_copy.begin(), _copy.end()};
            source.reset();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Data() = default;
};
```

[Here's a link for compiling an example.](https://onlinegdb.com/ZGmGSIs__)

Any kind of feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `std::pair` rather than `std::variant`? That is, will a request ever return a useful error code and useful data that are both needed? Or is the data valid if and only if the error code is not success?

Comment: And do you need runtime polymorphism, or could do you have the option to replace `std::function` with a template parameter for the functor type?

Comment: Hi, I'll look into `std::variant`, but error codes does return on every request, with a potential data in return that can hold a reason string or other information.

Comment: Can you clarify the polymorphism point?. Per `std::function` I think it's needed so to keep and register callback functions at one place.. If it will be useful, I can link the code I got insighted from.

Comment: Right, but if the request succeeds, does the error contain any important information other than, *There was no error*? If the request fails, does it return any data? If not, this is a classic use case for a discriminated union.

Comment: By polymorphism, what I mean is, storing a function pointer will have lower overhead than storing a `std::function` object, and a function pointer can be `constexpr`. and optimize better. If the functor type is one of your template parameters, you can still use `std::function` in those cases where the type of the callback is not known at compile time, or the same data structure needs to hold calllbacks of many types. But your program can also get the more-efficient version when it can.

Comment: I see, If no error it might return data (Not always), this is also applies if there's an error as reason string (at the current design).

Comment: As an example to the first context, there's an instance wherein I want to reset any WiFi static IPs (gateway,static,subnet), the command just executes with OK and no return value (Empty string). Contraversely, a command to alter a state which is not accepted, returns an error with the current state as an input.

Comment: Per function pointers, consider that the entities are classes instances, hooking currently requires a lambda function captures [this] to call the member function. Please inform if there's any example for template+function pointers utilization. If any help I was insighted from this [framework](https://github.com/HamzaHajeir/h4plugins/tree/master) that I maintain after the passage of its author. You can track `H4Service::_addLocals`,  and `H4P_SerialCmd::invokeCmd` for a complete cycle.

Comment: You might use `std::bind` on a member function pointer, for a closure on non-static member functions. In any case, the template version will also work on a lambda expression.

Comment: I see, that's correct. Per template version I'm searching for a good reference explaining it, I appreciate if you can recommend one.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question has caused answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you modify the code ask a new follow up question with a link back to this question if you want the new code reviewed.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir When we allow askers to edit the question then on-lookers tend to come across the post and downvote the first answers with comments like "the code doesn't have x, why are you talking about x? Your answer is useless." Comments like the example aren't helpful and only harm the site. Asking a new question isn't really much of an ask of you, and helps keep the interactions on the site good.

Comment: Hi @Peilonrayz, I agree with preventing editing the code itself, this is full of sense and I didn't revert to editing the code. What I've edited is adding an **UPDATE** section with updated code and referring to the answer. Have you or pacmaninbw read that prior the judge?

Comment: Hi @Davislor, here's an [updated question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286492/c-system-data-transfer-design-following-1) with updated codebase.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir The issues with "update"s is more intricate and harder to explain in comments due to a lack of characters. I'd hoped you could have extrapolated from the simpler situation to the more complex one, rather than flying off the handle.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The update was added to the question, not within comments. As this site isn't a thread that can hold updates by scrolling down, this is the logical way of updating a codebase that I can see! So neither answering or asking another question seems a logical way to me. As there might happens several updates until a final answer is concluded. See my other question seems not so attractive, that's perhaps because I need to re-explain the full picture in every new question added. And neither answering with a design/code that needs further review seems logical to me per the site design.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir You have misunderstood my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Minor issues

- Code formatting: the code is very dense and hard to read. Sometimes it is hard to see where a function ends. Avoid multiple statements per line. I suggest you use a [code formatting tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier) to automate this.
- [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-Namespace), especially in header files. As for one of the problems it has: note that C++23 will introduce [`std::print()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print), so suddenly your `print()` will start shadowing C++23's version of it.
- [Prefer using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n).
- Consider using [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) instead of `std::uint8_t`.

## Span or copy, pick one.

Your class stores both a `std::span` to some data that might live outside of the class, and a `std::vector` to hold some data inside the class. This is very confusing: does `Data` own the data or not? It seems that it depends on whether you want to store a string in it or binary data; in the former case it will leave `_copy` empty and just use `_span`. But it's a bit unsafe: what if I write:

```
Data foo(std::string("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n"));
std::cout << foo.as_string(); // Oops!
```

When `foo()` gets constructed, it creates a span of the *temporary* string object. That string object is gone after the first line has been executed. The second line which tries to print the contents will thus reference data which no longer exists. A tool like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) will find the error in the above code.

It's safer to always make a copy, and to remove `_span` altogether. If you really want to be able to hold a reference to external data, I would make a separate class for that named `DataReference`, so it's made explicit what this is doing.

## Don't cast away `const`ness

Your class also has a problem because you are using `const_cast`. Consider this:

```
Data foo("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n");
foo.data()[0] = 0; // Oops!
```

This will compile, but since the actual string lives in read-only memory, the second line will cause a segmentation fault. In general, avoid casting away `const`ness, it is there for a reason. This is another reason to always store a copy.

## Consider using `std::variant`

Your class either stores a (reference to a) string or some binary data. It's very similar to what you can do with [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Consider:

```
using Data = std::variant<std::string, std::vector<std::uint8_t>>;
```

Or if you really wanted to store strings by reference but store data by value:

```
using Data = std::variant<std::string_view, std::vector<std::uint8_t>>;
```

Working with `std::variant`s directly is perhaps not as easy as with your class, but you can make freestanding functions out of the member functions you had:

```
std::string as_string(const Data& data) {
    return std::visit([](auto& data) {
        // This works for std::string, std::string_view and std::vector.
        return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size());
    }, data);
}
```

And use it like:

```
Data foo("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n");
std::cout << as_string(foo);
```

## Generic hooks

> ```
> std::function<std::pair<ERROR_CODE,std::vector<Data>>(const std::string& resourceLink, const std::vector<Data>& payload)>;
> ```

So you want to be able to register a function that takes any number of arguments and returns any number of values? Sure that will work, but now *you* have to check in the functions that you register that `payload.size()` has the expected length, and the caller has to check that the return values' `second.size()` has the expected size, and they have to check for each item in those vectors whether it is the expected string or binary data type.

It would be better if the compiler could do the checking for you. You might want to post another question here with more of the code so we can see how it is actually used, and maybe then we can see if there is a better solution.

Comment: Before anything, I'd thank you very much for the time you dedicated to answer the question. Per the minor issues you're correct in all of them, I'm don't rely on `using namespace std` in the code. Useful for `std::endl` and also it's not used in the code (still using `printf()` and will upgrade to std::format() at some point in future). I'll consider `std::byte`. And I'll update with better formatted code (with some upgrades regarding temporary data).

Comment: For the data received by network libraries, the data is just there and avoiding copy is vital for embedded systems, avoiding copy will reduce heap fragmentation and OOM issues in general. That's why referencing can really help. In another instances copying is important to extend the lifetime of data held by a scoped object. I'll update post with the class `Data` having more ways to copy data. Per `const_cast`, you're again correct and I'm aware of this, but it's not intended to be used by this way honestly. Perhaps having const `_span` and/or `_copy` that can only be mutated within the class?

Comment: *“it's not intended to be used by this way”* I can understand that. However, it's easy to forget what exactly the intended use cases are, especially if multiple people are working on the same code base. So if it is possible, I would try to design it in such a way that these mistakes just cannot happen. You could change the constructors so they only take non-`const` pointers to strings; this then avoids the need for the `const_cast`. Or alternatively, you can make it so `data()` returns a `const` pointer. It's hard to say what is better, that depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: I see, both options are valid, but the first one has an issue against `const char*` (else if I delete it and rely on `std::string`), so `const uint8_t* data()` approach is taken currently. As I see by `std::variant` proposed solution it requires memory allocation and I don't think it's a preferred approach due to reasons explained earlier, besides that, we need actually one memory storage, and ways to interpret it (hence the current concept).

Comment: Per _Generic hooks_ it's correct that in some cases there need to be size checking that needs to be specified beforehand, but also allows for either empty responses/inputs or muti input/output (e.g Available WiFi SSIDs, which are glued together with a delimeter of `oxff` at the current impl.). Per the bigger picture: The core design is insighted from a [framework](https://github.com/HamzaHajeir/h4plugins/tree/master) I maintain now after the passage of its auther, one can track `H4Service::_addLocals`, and `H4P_SerialCmd::invokeCmd` for a complete cycle.If it's unclear I can make another post.

Comment: I think a solution is to copy data by default, that fixes the returning issues. And wherein it's needed to pass an allocated data as a parameter, I can now explicitly disable copying.  Please check the updated code.

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) does not do any dynamic memory allocation. It's basically equivalent to a `union` plus some state to remember which union member is currently active.

Comment: Got it, but it cant use a referenced value to avoid copy (as `std::variant<std::string&, std::vector<uint8_t>&>`). So for now the issue is splitted into two parts: passing as argument (no copy needed), and returning from a function (copy is needed). For now it can perfectly work in returning.

Comment: You can with [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), or by using `std::variant<std::string_view, std::span<uint8_t>>` instead of references.

Comment: Ah I was thinking of more complex design (DataReference class) that inherits Data and override some constructors, removing the copy flag. But a good solution is here also. the reference is just `std::variant<std::string_view, std:span<uint8_t>>` and for the data returning is `std::variant<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>>`.  I'll think if I really need some functionality or considering some unknown issues at the moment!

Comment: Hi @g-sliepen, here's an [updated question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286492/c-system-data-transfer-design-following-1) regarding the design.