# C++ System data transfer design - Following 1

Tags: c++, c++20

Based on the [previous question regarding Data transfer design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286421/c-system-data-transfer-design), here's a major updated code per G. Sliepen's Answer recommendation per `std::variant`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>

enum class RequestErrors : uint8_t
{
    OK,
    NOT_FOUND,

};
using DataReference = std::variant<std::string_view, std::span<uint8_t>>;
using Data = std::variant<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>>;

using DataReferenceContainer = std::vector<DataReference>;
using DataContainer = std::vector<Data>;

class RequestPayload
{
    DataReferenceContainer ploads;

public:
            std::size_t         size()          const { return ploads.size(); };
            auto                begin()         const { return ploads.begin(); }
            auto                end()           const { return ploads.end(); }
            auto&               front()         const { return ploads.front(); }
            auto&               back()          const { return ploads.back(); }

            auto&               getVector()     const { return ploads; }

    RequestPayload(const char *str) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::string_view{str}}) {}
    RequestPayload(const char *str, size_t len) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::string_view{str, len}}) {}
    RequestPayload(const std::string &str) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{str}) {}
    RequestPayload(const std::string_view sv) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{sv}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::vector<uint8_t> &vec) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::span<uint8_t>{vec.begin(), vec.size()}}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::span<uint8_t> span) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{span}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::initializer_list<DataReference> list) : ploads(list) {}
    RequestPayload(const DataReferenceContainer &ref) : ploads(ref) {}
};

class ConcreteData
{
    DataContainer rets;

public:
            std::size_t         size() const { return rets.size(); };
            auto                begin() const { return rets.begin(); }
            auto                end() const { return rets.end(); }
            auto&               front() const { return rets.front(); }
            auto&               back() const { return rets.back(); }

            auto&               getVector() { return rets; }

    ConcreteData(const char *str) : rets(DataContainer{std::string{str}}) {}
    ConcreteData(const char *str, size_t len) : rets(DataContainer{std::string{str, len}}) {}
    ConcreteData(const std::string &str) : rets(DataContainer{str}) {}
    ConcreteData(const std::string_view sv) : rets(DataContainer{std::string(sv.data(), sv.length())}) {}
    ConcreteData(std::vector<uint8_t> &vec) : rets(DataContainer{vec}) {}
    ConcreteData(std::span<uint8_t> span) : rets(DataContainer{std::vector<uint8_t>{span.begin(), span.end()}}) {}
    ConcreteData(std::initializer_list<Data> list) : rets(list) {}
    ConcreteData(const DataContainer &ref) : rets(ref) {}

    ConcreteData(const RequestPayload &rhs)
    {
        for (auto &reqData : rhs.getVector())
        {
            if (auto *rd = std::get_if<std::string_view>(&reqData))
            {
                std::string d{rd->data(), rd->size()};
                rets.emplace_back(d);
            }
            else if (auto *rd = std::get_if<std::span<uint8_t>>(&reqData))
            {
                std::vector<uint8_t> d{rd->begin(), rd->end()};
                rets.emplace_back(d);
            }
        }
    }

    ConcreteData& operator=(const RequestPayload &rhs)
    {
        // No need to check (this!=&rhs).
        rets.clear();
        rets.shrink_to_fit();
        auto& rhsVec = rhs.getVector();
        rets.reserve(rhsVec.size());
        for (auto &reqData : rhsVec)
        {
            if (auto *rd = std::get_if<std::string_view>(&reqData))
            {
                std::string d{rd->data(), rd->size()};
                rets.emplace_back(d);
            }
            else if (auto *rd = std::get_if<std::span<uint8_t>>(&reqData))
            {
                std::vector<uint8_t> d{rd->begin(), rd->end()};
                rets.emplace_back(d);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

using ReturnData = ConcreteData;
using RequestReturn = std::pair<RequestErrors, ReturnData>;

using CallbackSignature = std::function<RequestReturn(const std::string &context, const RequestPayload &)>;

/* Simplified SystemInterface */
class SystemInterface
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, CallbackSignature> requests;

public:
    void addRequest(const std::string &name, CallbackSignature cbf)
    {
        requests[name] = cbf;
    }
    RequestReturn execCmd(const std::string &name, const std::string &context, const RequestPayload &payload)
    {
        if (requests.count(name))
        {
            return requests[name](context, payload);
        }
        return std::make_pair(RequestErrors::NOT_FOUND, DataContainer{});
    }
};
```

[Here's a working example based on this codebase.](https://onlinegdb.com/h-B6WnqxSJ)

I appreciate any kind of feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `#include` Headers in Alphabetical Order

Or group them into categories, like angled `<headers>` first followed by quoted `"header.h"`, keeping each category in order.  That makes it *much* easier to spot when a header is already included or not.

### Spell Identifiers Correctly

You didn’t dump all of `namespace std` into the global namespace.  You also used `<cstdint>` instead of `<stdint.h>`  Bravo, kudos, and yasher koach!

However, that means you should be using `std::uint8_t` instead of `uint8_t`.  Implementations are allowed to make `uint8_t` an alias for `std::uint8_t`, and I believe all the popular ones do, but it’s not technically standard-conforming unless you write `using std::uint8_t;`.  And you don’t want a header file you write to pollute the global namespave.

### About Those Constructors

You currently have:

```
ConcreteData(const char *str)
ConcreteData(const char *str, size_t len)
ConcreteData(const std::string &str)
ConcreteData(const std::string_view sv)
ConcreteData(std::vector<uint8_t> &vec)
ConcreteData(std::span<uint8_t> span)
ConcreteData(std::initializer_list<Data> list)
ConcreteData(const DataContainer &ref)
```

There are a number of errors here.

#### Add Back the Default, Copy and Move Constructors

Because you wrote constructors of your own, the compiler will not create any default constructors, so for example you can no longer declare

```
RequestPayload payload;
```

You’ve also made your class uncopyable and unmoveable.  Re-enable these constructors with `= default`:

```
RequestPayload() = default;
RequestPayload(const RequestPayload&) = default;
RequestPayload(RequestPayload&&) = default;
```

One of your classes also declares an assignment operator, and you should also declare these by the Rule of Five:

```
RequestPayload& operator=(const RequestPayload&) = default;
RequestPayload& operator=(RequestPayload&&) = default;
~RequestPayload() = default; // Must be virtual if you intend to make this a base class.
```

#### Make Constructors `explicit` (if Appropriate)

One of the few that cannot be `explicit` is the initializer-list, since you will typically want to initialize from one variant and not have to write out the conversion to `Data` explicitly:

```cpp
    const ConcreteData dataList = {"hello"s,
                                   "world"s,
                                   std::vector<std::uint8_t>{1,2,3}};
```

Another useful one to not make `explicit` is the converting constructor from `const std::string_view`, since that’s an efficient conversion from many stringy types that store their data contiguously.  Having saves you from writing another converting constructor for `const std::string&` (although you might want an `explicit` move constructor from `std::string&&`).  In my opinion, many `std::string` conversions are too expensive to happen implicitly.

For most of the others, you do not want surprises.  For example, you might not want to have every type with a conversion to `std::string` use it implicitly.

#### Use Move Constructors Whenever Possible

Your internal `rets` is a `std::vector`, which is moveable.  Furthermore, it's a `std::vector` of a `std::variant` of moveable types.  This implies that you should be writing converting constructors with move overloads, and let the compiler implement things like assignment operators from those.

#### Consider Adding Template Converting Constructors

This can get a little complicated, but let’s walk through `ConcreteData` as an example.

First, all of these examples will get much easier to read if we define a few helper templates:

```cpp
// A counterpart to std::same as that compares the underlying types.
// Suitable for checking the value types of ranges.
template<typename T, typename U>
concept different_from = !std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, std::remove_cvref_t<U>>;

// Dereferences a multi-dimensional range by one level.
template<std::ranges::input_range T>
using row_t = std::remove_cvref_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;

// Dereferences a multi-dimensional range by two levels.
template<class T>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
              std::ranges::input_range<row_t<T>>)
using column_t = std::remove_cvref_t<
    std::ranges::range_value_t<
        std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>>;

// A range whose elements can be moved.
template<class T, typename Data>
concept container_of_movable =
    std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
    std::indirectly_movable<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>, Data*>;
```

Right now, you have an assignment operator from `RequestPayload` to `ConcreteData`.  First, this should be a converting constructor.  Second, it isn’t really a conversion from `RequestPayload` only.  There’s no reason you couldn’t convert from a `DataReferenceContainer` instead.  Or any other container that holds `DataReference` objects: the logic is identical.  You iterate over `begin` and `end`, so the `concept` you want here is a `range` with the appropriate value type.  One possible implementation:

```cpp
    // Initializes a list from a container of DataReference
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<row_t<T>, DataReference>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::string_view>(x)) {
                rets.emplace_back(std::string{std::get<std::string_view>(x)});
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::span<std::uint8_t>>(x)) {
                const auto span = std::get<std::span<std::uint8_t>>(x);
                rets.emplace_back(std::vector<std::uint8_t>{span.begin(), span.end()});
            } else { // Unreachable!
                std::cout.flush(); // Don't cross the streams!
                std::cerr << "Logic Error: a DataReference held an impossible type!\n";
                std::abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

We also want to be able to copy from any container or range of `Data`, not just the `DataContainer` type:

```cpp
    // Initializes a list from a range of Data
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<row_t<T>, Data>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(x);
        }
    }
```

You currently have a

```
ConcreteData(const DataContainer &ref) : rets(ref) {}
```

This is incorrect: it can neither read a `const DataContainer&`, nor does it optimize to a move constructor when it can, nor does it constant-fold an empty container.  Replace it with:

```
explicit constexpr ConcreteData(DataContainer &&ref) : rets{std::move(ref)} {}
```

You also, as mentioned earlier, should declare a `default` move constructor, as:

```
ConcreteData(ConcreteData&&) = default;
```

The copy constructor we already implemented can cover the versions of both that copy instead of moving.

Now, the last two constructors cover the case where you can move from the source container to the destination container, but even when you can’t do that, you might be able to move each item from the source container, one by one.  It is much better to move a large number of strings and vectors than make deep copies of all the data you’re about to discard anyway!

```cpp
    // Initializes a list from a range of moveable objects
    template<class T> requires
        container_of_movable<T, Data>
    constexpr ConcreteData(T&& source) {
        for (auto&& x : source) {
           rets.emplace_back(std::move(x));
        }
    }
```

Finally, it would be convenient to be able to initialize our container of `Data` objects from two-dimensional containers, depending on whether their contents are stringy or not.  If we take any two-dimensional container of `char` as a container of stringy things, those might look like:

```cpp
    // Initialize a list from a range of byte ranges:
    template<class T> requires (
        std::convertible_to<column_t<T>, std::uint8_t> &&
        different_from<column_t<T>, char>)
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(std::vector<std::uint8_t>{std::ranges::begin(x), std::ranges::end(x)});
        }
    }

    // Initializes a list from a range of stringy types:
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<column_t<T>, char>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(std::string{std::ranges::begin(x), std::ranges::end(x)});
        }
    }
```

You might not want these, especially if your implementation defines both `char` and `uint8_t` as aliases for `unsigned char`.  If you prefer, you can make the byte data `std::byte` or make the condition that the rows convert to `std::string`.

### Use `constexpr` and `noexcept` Where Applicable

These can improve optimization.

### Add `const` Overloads

You need these to be able to do anything useful on `const` instances.  For example, it is currently not possible to call `getContainer()` on a `const` instance of `ConcreteData`.  You want:

```
constexpr auto&       getvector() noexcept { return rets; }
constexpr const auto& getVector() const noexcept { return rets; }
```

### Implement Equality Operators

The default `operator==` will work, although I prefer to explicitly `default` them.  However, you have a large number of classes that are comparable with each other: it should, for example, be possible to compare a `DataContainer` and `ConcreteData`. or `RequestPayload`.

In cases like this, for overloads to resolve correctly, you want to declare the equality operator as a non-member function.  A possible implementation is:

```cpp
constexpr bool operator==(const ConcreteData& left, const DataContainer& right) noexcept {
    return left.getVector() == right;
}

constexpr bool operator==(const DataContainer& left, const ConcreteData& right) noexcept {
    return left == right.getVector();
}
```

If you didn’t add a `const` overload for `getVector()`, you would need to declare these `friend` functions in `DataContainer`.

Once you do this, the compiler will add `!=` automatically.

### Add `swap` as Member and Non-Member Functions

Some compilers (such as Clang) will do this for you automatically, but I don’t believe that’s portable, and many algorithms use `swap`.  Always implement this whenever you can do so efficiently.

### Return a `variant` or `optional`, not a `pair`

You currently have

```
using RequestReturn = std::pair<RequestErrors, ReturnData>;
```

where

```cpp
enum class RequestErrors : uint8_t
{
    OK,
    NOT_FOUND,

};
```

However, the return value is always **either** valid data **or** an error, not both.  This means it should be a `std::variant`, not a `std::pair`.

Returning a sum type like `std::variant` means you no longer need an `OK` error value: the absence of an error is instead represented by the return value holding something other than `RequestErrors`.

But that means that there is only one possible value of `RequestErrors`.  If that’s only because this is a simplified example where you left the other possible errors out, you can keep the class.  However, if the class doesn’t store any useful information about the error (that a program can act on, and could not deduce from the mere fact that an error occurred at that point), there is no need for it to exist.  You could return a `std::optional<ReturnData>` instead, and let `.has_value()` indicate success.

### Consider Generic Invocable Callbacks

You mention in a comment that the `SystemInterface` is “simplified,” so I’m not sure whether or not changing `CallbackSignature` to a generic `std::invocable` template parameter would get you anything, or just be needless complication.  I suspect the latter.  If you’re always passing an object-instance pair, though, it might be slightly more efficient to store `std::bind` of a member funtion and instance pointer than a `std::function`.

### Implement the Rest of the Container Interface

You’ve implemented enough of the interface that it’s annoying to have to remember what’s not included, and you should just implement every other part of it that people actually use.

### Consider Removing the Classes and Using Vectors

Really, `RequestPayload` and `ConcreteData` have **are-a** relationships to `std::vector`: THey’re vectors plus some extra constructors that can be passed to certain parts of your API.  The implementation uses a lot of boilerplate just to say that multiple classes are vectors with some extra containers.  It your implementation supports it, it would be more efficient to instead have them inherit from `std::vector` than to say, line by line, that it implements each and every part of the `vector` class by forwarding it to its one data member.

You might also replace the special constructors with factory functions that return `std::vector`, since that is how you implement all the converting constructors anyway.

If you intentionally don’t want to allow inserting items into a `ConcreteData` or `RequestPayload` instance after it is constructed, you can `delete` or override those member functions.

### Putting it All Together

Here’s a starting-point that primarily makes changes to `ConcreteData`.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// A counterpart to std::same as that compares the underlying types.
// Suitable for checking the value types of ranges.
template<typename T, typename U>
concept different_from = !std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, std::remove_cvref_t<U>>;

// Dereferences a multi-dimensional range by one level.
template<std::ranges::input_range T>
using row_t = std::remove_cvref_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;

// Dereferences a multi-dimensional range by two levels.
template<class T>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
              std::ranges::input_range<row_t<T>>)
using column_t = std::remove_cvref_t<
    std::ranges::range_value_t<
        std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>>;

// A range whose elements can be moved.
template<class T, typename Data>
concept container_of_movable =
    std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
    std::indirectly_movable<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>, Data*>;

enum class RequestErrors : uint8_t
{
    OK,
    NOT_FOUND,

};
using DataReference = std::variant<std::string_view, std::span<uint8_t>>;
using Data = std::variant<std::string, std::vector<std::uint8_t>>;

using DataReferenceContainer = std::vector<DataReference>;
using DataContainer = std::vector<Data>;

class RequestPayload
{
    DataReferenceContainer ploads;

public:
            std::size_t         size()          const { return ploads.size(); };
            auto                begin()         const { return ploads.begin(); }
            auto                end()           const { return ploads.end(); }
            auto&               front()         const { return ploads.front(); }
            auto&               back()          const { return ploads.back(); }

            auto&               getVector()     const { return ploads; }

    RequestPayload() = default;
    RequestPayload(const RequestPayload&) = default;
    RequestPayload(RequestPayload&&) = default;
    RequestPayload& operator=(const RequestPayload&) = default;
    RequestPayload& operator=(RequestPayload&&) = default;
    ~RequestPayload() = default; // Must be virtual if you intend to make this a base class.

    RequestPayload(const char *str) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::string_view{str}}) {}
    RequestPayload(const char *str, size_t len) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::string_view{str, len}}) {}
    RequestPayload(const std::string &str) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{str}) {}
    RequestPayload(const std::string_view sv) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{sv}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::vector<uint8_t> &vec) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{std::span<uint8_t>{vec.begin(), vec.size()}}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::span<uint8_t> span) : ploads(DataReferenceContainer{span}) {}
    RequestPayload(std::initializer_list<DataReference> list) : ploads(list) {}
    RequestPayload(const DataReferenceContainer &ref) : ploads(ref) {}
};


class ConcreteData
{
    DataContainer rets;

public:
    using iterator        = typename decltype(rets)::iterator;
    using const_iterator  = typename decltype(rets)::const_iterator;
    using pointer         = typename decltype(rets)::pointer;
    using const_pointer   = typename decltype(rets)::const_pointer;
    using reference       = typename decltype(rets)::reference;
    using const_reference = typename decltype(rets)::const_reference;
    using value_type      = typename decltype(rets)::value_type;

    constexpr std::size_t     size() const noexcept { return rets.size(); };
    constexpr iterator        begin() noexcept {return rets.begin();}
    constexpr const_iterator  begin() const noexcept { return rets.begin(); }
    constexpr iterator        end() noexcept {return rets.end();}
    constexpr const_iterator  end() const noexcept  { return rets.end(); }
    constexpr reference       front() noexcept { return rets.front(); }
    constexpr const_reference front() const noexcept { return rets.front(); }
    constexpr reference       back() noexcept { return rets.back(); }
    constexpr const_reference back() const noexcept { return rets.back(); }
    constexpr pointer         data() noexcept {return rets.data();}
    constexpr const_pointer   data() const noexcept {return rets.data();}
    constexpr auto&           getvector() noexcept { return rets; }
    constexpr const auto&     getVector() const noexcept { return rets; }    // TODO: You should implement the rest of the container interface.
    // TODO: You should implement all of the container interface.

    ConcreteData() = default;
    ConcreteData(const ConcreteData&) = default;
    ConcreteData(ConcreteData&&) = default;
    explicit constexpr ConcreteData(const char *str, size_t len) : rets{std::string{str, len}} {}
    explicit constexpr ConcreteData(const char *str) : rets{std::string{str}} {}
    constexpr ConcreteData(std::initializer_list<Data> list) : rets{list} {}
    explicit constexpr ConcreteData(DataContainer &&ref) : rets{std::move(ref)} {}
    constexpr ConcreteData(const std::string_view str) : rets{std::string{str}} {}
    explicit constexpr ConcreteData(std::string&& str) : rets{std::move(str)} {}
    explicit constexpr ConcreteData(std::vector<std::uint8_t>&& vec) : rets{std::move(vec)} {}

    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const char (&str)[N]) : rets{std::string{str, N}} {}

    // Initialize a singleton list from a range of bytes:
    template<class T>
        requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
                  std::convertible_to<row_t<T>, std::uint8_t> &&
                  !std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view> &&
                  different_from<T, DataContainer> &&
                  different_from<T, ConcreteData>)
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source)
     : rets{std::vector<std::uint8_t>{std::ranges::begin(source), std::ranges::end(source)}}
    {}

    // Initialize a list from a range of byte ranges:
    template<class T> requires (
        std::convertible_to<column_t<T>, std::uint8_t> &&
        different_from<column_t<T>, char>)
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(std::vector<std::uint8_t>{std::ranges::begin(x), std::ranges::end(x)});
        }
    }

    // Initializes a list from a range of stringy types:
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<column_t<T>, char>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(std::string{std::ranges::begin(x), std::ranges::end(x)});
        }
    }

    // Initializes a list from a range of Data
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<row_t<T>, Data>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            rets.emplace_back(x);
        }
    }

    // Initializes a list from a container of DataReference
    template<class T> requires
        std::same_as<row_t<T>, DataReference>
    constexpr ConcreteData(const T& source) {
        for (const auto& x : source) {
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::string_view>(x)) {
                rets.emplace_back(std::string{std::get<std::string_view>(x)});
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::span<std::uint8_t>>(x)) {
                const auto span = std::get<std::span<std::uint8_t>>(x);
                rets.emplace_back(std::vector<std::uint8_t>{span.begin(), span.end()});
            } else { // Unreachable!
                std::cout.flush(); // Don't cross the streams!
                std::cerr << "Logic Error: a DataReference held an impossible type!\n";
                std::abort();
            }
        }
    }

    // Initializes a list from a range of moveable objects
    template<class T> requires
        container_of_movable<T, Data>
    constexpr ConcreteData(T&& source) {
        for (auto&& x : source) {
           rets.emplace_back(std::move(x));
        }
    }

    constexpr void swap(ConcreteData& other) noexcept {
        rets.swap(other.rets);
    }

    ConcreteData& operator=(const ConcreteData&) = default;
    ConcreteData& operator=(ConcreteData&&) = default;
    bool operator==(const ConcreteData&) const = default;
    ~ConcreteData() = default; // Needs to be virtual if this is a base class.
};

constexpr void swap(ConcreteData& x, ConcreteData& y) noexcept {
    x.swap(y);
}

constexpr bool operator==(const ConcreteData& left, const DataContainer& right) noexcept {
    return left.getVector() == right;
}

constexpr bool operator==(const DataContainer& left, const ConcreteData& right) noexcept {
    return left == right.getVector();
}

using ReturnData = ConcreteData;
using RequestReturn = std::pair<RequestErrors, ReturnData>;

using CallbackSignature = std::function<RequestReturn(const std::string &context, const RequestPayload &)>;

/* Simplified SystemInterface */
class SystemInterface
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, CallbackSignature> requests;

public:
    void addRequest(const std::string &name, CallbackSignature cbf)
    {
        requests[name] = cbf;
    }
    RequestReturn execCmd(const std::string &name, const std::string &context, const RequestPayload &payload)
    {
        if (requests.count(name))
        {
            return requests[name](context, payload);
        }
        return std::make_pair(RequestErrors::NOT_FOUND, ConcreteData{});
    }
};
```

And a very basic test driver with only partial coverage:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;
using std::uint8_t;

static_assert(std::indirectly_movable<std::ranges::iterator_t<std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>&&>, std::vector<uint8_t>*>);

int main()
{
    constexpr char hello[] = "hello, world!";
    const ConcreteData data1 = hello;
    const ConcreteData dataList = {"hello"s,
                                   "world"s,
                                   std::vector<std::uint8_t>{1,2,3}};
    constexpr uint8_t matrix[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    const ConcreteData dataMatrix = matrix;
    constexpr std::string_view string_table[] = {"hello"sv, "world!"sv};
    const ConcreteData dataStrins = string_table;
    const ConcreteData fromContainer = DataContainer{"hello"s, "world"s};
    std::string tempArray[] = {"hello"s, "world"s};
    const ConcreteData fromTempArray = std::move(tempArray);
    uint8_t toSpan[] = {1, 2, 3};
    const DataReferenceContainer refs = {"hello"sv,
                                         "world"sv,
                                         std::span<uint8_t>{toSpan}};
    const ConcreteData fromRefs = refs;
    assert(fromRefs != DataContainer{});
    assert(DataContainer{} != fromRefs);
    const DataReference refArray[] = {"hello"sv,
                                      "world"sv,
                                      std::span<uint8_t>{toSpan}};
    const ConcreteData fromRefArray = refArray;
    assert(fromRefs == fromRefArray);
    ConcreteData copyData = fromRefArray;
    const ConcreteData moveData = std::move(fromRefArray);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[And a link to the Godbolt compiler explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/9TW917fPj)

Comment: Thank you very much @Davislor for the time and effort put into answering the question. 
The answer shows an advanced usage of C++ features with templates, an area I don't have much knowledge and experience with. I'll further read about each function called to deeply grasp it. Until then, I'll consider `std::uint8_t`, It's a good note to add missing constructors and `operator=`, I'll read and adapt with `noexcept` and `constexpr`, and check for the `swap()`. I think it's a good idea to inherit from `std::vector` for the contained data. I'll also read about `std::invocable`.

Comment: It worths to mention that in an updated codebase I've added const keywords to the APIs, and made `ReferenceData` a class, to be able to change its value on runtime by an introduced `Guarder` class, where a user (me :)) can add specific guarders to payloads that are checked systemically by the SystemInterface prior calling cbf. One of Guarders is `toStringGuarder` that converts `span` payload(s) to `string_view` if printable `all_of("Data",isprint)` (This is the only reason currently for an introduced class). Per returning `std::variant<error,DataContainer>` I'll reinvestigate and back soon.

Comment: I'd thank you again @davislor, I've applied the updates you've pinpointed. Per the SystemInterface return type I'll keep it now as `std::pair` to meet the current needs, until an enough mature decision to keep it or switching to `std::variant` happens. However, I've some questions regarding the solutions provided: 1) I think I can remove the "unreachable" `else` branch in `ConcreteData` constructor of `DataReference`, correct? 2) What main changes I need to switch to inheriting from `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: 3) GCC (up to 11.4) can't compile the code due to error complaining calling to non-constexpr function, to almost all `ConcreteData` constructors and APIs, beside the `operator==` calls outside the class. What can solve this issue until the platform support GCC 12.1 upwards? Thanks

Comment: All callback function signatures are unified to `RequestReturn(const std::string &context, const RequestPayload &)` which are member functions of classes, no free-standing functions, those aren't reachable directly by the `SystemInterface` per the design.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Re-reading, I notice one error: I somehow missed the `const` in `ConcreteData(const DataContainer &ref)`. So my statement that this wouldn't work on a `const DataContainer&` was wrong.

Comment: Well in this community I think I'd pre-accepting the answers, frankly; 1) It's a review that will add at least something unknown to the asker, 2) Really helpful answers that's unfair not to appreciate.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could find the time answering the concerns pinpointed within the comments above. Thanks @Davislor

Comment: @HamzaHajeir This code compiles correctly on GCC 12 and up. I think older versions aren’t declaring all the standard library functions `constexpr` that should be in C++20. Can you upgrade your compiler version? If not, a workaround would be to remove the `constexpr` specifier from the functions that don’t compile (and then from any functions that call those)

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Did you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks. what considerations/changes do I need to perform after inheriting from `std::vector<Data>` and `std::vector<DataReference>` beside removing the redundant APIs? if any.

Comment: Hi @Davislor, I'm reading about inheriting from `std::vector` but it seems a discouraged action there over the Internet, found some strict opinions not to, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers/7110262#7110262). What do you think with our case?

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Point one, about the lack of `virtual` destructors, is completely correct, but applies when working with a polymorphic object through a base-class pointer. which you’re not doing here. Point two, about extension, I think is unlikely to be a problem here, because you’re only adding converting constructors you would need to implement anyway. There’s a whole lot more boilerplate to shadow the entire `std::vector` interface.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir However, an alternative would be to just write factory functions that return a `std::vector`, and have your API take those. It does rule out hiding any of the implementation details`.

Comment: Thanks Davislor, I do have now a working code that inherits `std::vector`, but I didn't get the purpose of tranaforming the converting constructors to factory functions, honestly. Perhaps to be more explicit, as `fromStrings()` or `fromByteRange()`...?

Comment: Well, the only part that doesn't work as expected is the equality operator (Sementation Fault), it became an equality operator between the base and the derived class. [MCVE](https://godbolt.org/z/5K1Pa5e7W)

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Well, the idea behind factory functions would be to keep the ability to convert containers of one type to containers of another type, while the containers themselves just become aliases for `std::vector`.  This could simplify them immensely.

Comment: Regarding the initializer from a range of bytes template, I think I can replace it with one takes `const std::span<std::uint8_t>&`,  I've tested with providing `std::array` and raw array `uint8_t arr[]` they have linked to it -with the template commented out-. Is there something wrong in removing that one? Thanks. ([Link to current WIP version](https://godbolt.org/z/hcfq5GMEj))

Comment: Here's a following [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287097/c-structural-requests-system-with-payload-management) that goes beyond the data types, to the SystemInterface itself.

Comment: Per the factory methods, should these return `std::vector<BasicXXXData>`, `XXXData`, or `XXXData&&`, do you think? (XXX: either Reference or Concrete. XXXData is the built class that inherits from (`std::vector<BasicXXXData>` aka `XXXDataContainer`) ).

Comment: @HamzaHajeir A factory function should normally return a `Foo` with no `*` or `&` decorating it. This uses guaranteed copy elision, which is more efficient than a move. If the factory can fail, without that being an error, it might return `std::optional`. Good ways to return several output parameters include `std::array`, `std::tuple` or a `struct`.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir A `std::vector` would be appropriate if you don’t know in advance how many elements you will be returning.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Another common idiom is to pass the output parameters by reference.